# logarithmic equations for beginners

Tags: logarithms

I just started learning logarithms and I'm having problems with one equations.

$\log_{\sqrt{x}}{2} + \log_{x}{4} = 4$

Sorry if I'm writing this wrong just for understanding ,I'm using this form 
log(b,a).

Comment: Hint: First show that the two summands on the left hand side are equal. Then simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Use that

$$\log_{\sqrt{x}} 2=\frac{\log 2}{\log \sqrt x}=\frac{\log 2}{\log x^{1/2}}=\frac{\log 2}{1/2\log x}=\frac{2\log 2}{\log x}=\frac{\log 2^2}{\log x}=\frac{\log 4}{\log x}$$ and

$$\log_x 4=\frac{\log 4}{\log x}.$$

Comment: Sorry, sqrt(x) and x are bases

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Is this a logarithmic rule? I mean are you using a trick or  can we do this with any logarithm

Comment: They are logarithmic rules: $\log_b a^n=n\log_b a$ and $\log_b a=\frac{\log_c a}{\log_c b}.$ As $c$ can be arbitrary we can choose $c=10.$

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert everything to the same base.

1.) log(sqrt(x),2) can be rewritten as 0.5*log(x,2)
2.) log(x,4) is the same as log(x,2)/log(x,4) which is again 0.5*log(x,2)

The equation then reduces to log(x,2) = 4
which gives x as 16

Comment: You are misunderstanding and is my fult,sqrt (x) is the base